# Parse UTF-8 HTML to CSV Ascii using Perl

Tags: perl

First off I am a little new to this, so the answer may be that it is up to the consumer, however, I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(RESPONSE,"response.xml")
$result ="";
while(<RESPONSE>){
  next unless $. > 1
  $line = $_
  $line =~ "<html><body>";
  $line =~ "</body></html>";
  $result .= $line
}
print "$result";
exit 0;
```

But this still outputs \n and \r\n explicitly. I tried adding the following...

```
use Encode
...
$final = decode_utf8($result);
print "$final";
```

But I still see the chars when I open up the doc generated by this shell command....

```
perl parse.pl > "outfile.csv"
```

So for example

```
<html><body>test,a\r\ntest2,b<body></html>
```

Stays as test,a\r\ntest2,b in the csv

Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to do, but it sure as hell has nothing to do with Unicode. Do you (A) want to translate DOS line endings to Unix, or do you (B) want to process escapes like `\n` and `\x42` to the characters they represent? In this case, writing the data back will destroy the CSV for most parsers.

Comment: Why wouldn't it? You didn't do anything to change `\r`, `\n`, carriage returns or newlines. I'm not sure what more than an explanation you want since you failed to ask any question.

Comment: Note that `\r`, `\n`, carriage returns and newlines are all encoded the same in both UTF-8 and ASCII, so I'm not sure why you mentioned ASCII, especially since you didn;t encode anything using ASCII.

Comment: Line 6 should have the affect of tossing the first line.
Lines 8 and 9 have no affect in this code; what did you desire?

I guess in general, what is it that you are trying to do?
What would you like the output to be?

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond.... a.) I am not a master encoder I am dangerously knowledgeable. so i am probably just misunderstanding something. B.) Yes there are some lines that do not really matter (Like how I throw out the first line) they are a byproduct of inexperience with perl. So basically I have a service that provides the html outcome provided. I want to strip it and turn the payload into a CSV file. I use a wget command to consume the service and perl to parse it.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm starting to see. Well, could you edit your question to include a minimal example of a typical HTML file you want to parse, and the CSV this should produce?

Comment: +amom I thought I had oops let me re do it.... Sorry just realized I used qoute instead of code should make sense now...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse HTML or XML then use an [HTML](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aParser) or [XML](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aParser) parser. If you want to create a CSV file then use a [CSV file module](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV).

This problem has nothing at all do to with the differences between Unicode and ASCII.